# Can I mount dead phone's partitions in VM?

Tags: data-recovery, linux, partitions, mount, vm

Dead phone. Have all partitions saved/read off internal memory including data partitions, all not encrypted, phone was rooted. Android 11 custom ROM, crDroid.
Need to mount data partition if possible, in Linux or Windows, doesn't matter.
Is there a way to mount all partitions in some ARM Android VM to recreate the phone with data? Had trouble mounting data partition in Linux. Thanks.

Comment: Partitions and data files are not CPU dependent and Android usually uses common file-systems like EXT4, thus you don't need a special VM. Just try to mount the data partition using a Linux system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mount unencrypted partition image on linux:

check file system whether is EXT4 or F2FS

```
$ xxd -l 1088 userdata.img | grep 53ef
$ xxd -l 1032 userdata.img | grep 1020.f5f2
```

for F2FS install additional package

```
$ sudo apt install f2fs-tools
```

mount the image with `/dev/loop?` created from losetup

```
$ mkdir data
$ sudo losetup -vf userdata.img
$ losetup -a
$ sudo mount -t ext4 -vo loop,ro,noload,noatime /dev/loop? data
$ sudo mount -t f2fs -vo loop,ro,norecovery,noatime /dev/loop? data
```

Note: WSL kernel doesn't support F2FS by default, linux only